# Subtract decimal days from pyspark current_timestamp

Tags: pyspark

In oracle,

```
SELECT SYSDATE -1.2, SYSDATE -1 FROM dual
```

Output:

```
SYSDATE-1.2        |SYSDATE-1          |
-------------------|-------------------|
2019-12-02 03:29:51|2019-12-02 08:17:51|
```

How to subtract decimal days e.g. 1.2 from `current_timestamp()` in pyspark

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT from_unixtime(unix_timestamp() - round(1.2*24*3600)` will do the job.

Source:

- [from_unixtime](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.from_unixtime)
- [unix_timestamp](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.unix_timestamp)